# Relationship between geometry and intution

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces, intuition

The question can be found below in the appropriate section. I basically wondered how intuition (especially geomtetric intuition) develops and developed historically, how this is justified and how they relate. The first sections are supposed to give some basic examples to hopefully make the question I am trying to more clearly.

### The real line $\mathbb{R}$

If we want to develop a mathematical concept of a line we have some properties in mind that our informal notion of a line should satisfy. We then use these properties to construct a formal definition of what a line should be and prove properties that our informal notion is expected to satisfy as well. These are for example, that it is infinite or that between any two points $a,b$ on that line, one can find a third point $c$ that lies between the two points $a,b$. We can define an object called $\mathbb{R}$ formally which happens to satisfy the properties we expect a line to have, so we regard $\mathbb{R}$ to be a model for a line, that is, when working with the real number line informally, any properties that we can derive that way should also be derivable for $\mathbb{R}$ since, intuitively, they are the same by our convention. This can then be done analogously for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ to justify, why we intuitively treat them to be equal to our informal notions of a plane and a space.

### The distance function

In a similar fashion, we have an informal notion of measuring distance along a line. This measure should have some properties that we expect it to have in our intuition, namely that the distance from a point $x$ to a point $y$ is positive and is $0$ if and only if we measure the distance from $x$ to itself. To not make this even larger I will leave out the other properties for a metric. In our formal setting, we can define a function $d$ that has exactly these properties and then call this a metric. Now, since it has the properties we expect a measure in our informal picture to have, we just treat them as equal, that is, again, that we expect anything to be correct formally that is correct in our intuition. This can then again be extended to norms when dealing with higher dimensions.

### The unit circle

In our intuition of the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can picture a circle of radius $1$ around around the origin. These are all the points that satisfy that their length is $1$. Since we previously had the intuition that length and the standard norm coincide, this should be the set of all points in our space, that have length one, that is $$S^1:=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ ||x||=1\}.$$ So again, anything that we expect the circle in our visualization to satisfy, should also be satisfied by our abstract definition of $S^1$, since we expect this abstract definition to capture our intuition correctly.

### What I think

What these examples are supposed to illustrate is what I came up with when trying to answer how formal concepts are related to intuition and pictures/visualizations and why this is justified. Strictly speaking, we have no certainty that our abstract constructions **are** the objects we visualize or even **model** them correctly. After all, our constructions are abstract and we have no guarantee that they are appropriate. As far as I can tell, the formal definitions appear to behave as if they are the objects that we visualize, so they are a good model, but it could be that for some definition, our formal construction has properties that we wouldn't expect a line to have. An example for that which is not related to geometry would be junk theorems about natural numbers. Since they are a good model however, we intuitively treat them to be equal and can often gather information or expectation of how the formal objects should behave. Of course, anything we derive intuitively still needs to be proven formally.

So in this way, we **first** have an intuitive notion, **then** formalize it and if it has the properties of our intuitive object, we **identify** them. That is, I suppose, how geometric intuition is developed: we have a geometric idea, formalize it and if it satisfies suitable properties, we treat this to be the idea we had.

### The Question

The question is basically what the relationship between formal constructions and visualizations/intuition is. Do we completely identify them intuitively as I thought? That is, when we derive a property visually, we expect it to be satisfied formally because we treat them as **equal**/ **identify them**?

Is this only a form of "implication" or is the "converse" also true? That is, if our formal construct satisfies a property, do we expect our informal notion to also satisfy this? This is somewhat related to the junk theorem point I mentioned earlier. If this is not the case, then **model** might be a better description than **identification**.

Comment: Do you know the books of Poincaré (The value of Science, Foundations of Science, Science and hypothesis) ? See [here](https://archive.org/details/foundationsscie01poingoog/page/n6/mode/2up)

Comment: No answer... Another reference "A Mathematician's apology" by Hardy.